# PaintComponent() method not being called with mouseMoved()

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to write a program that allows the user to create squares or circles by clicking on a JButton in a window, and then by clicking somewhere in the window (not on the button).

I currently am using two actionListeners for the different buttons that add a Square or Circle to an arrayList of type Shape (an interface that both square and circle implement). I have a class called frameListener which implements MouseListener and MouseMotionListener, which updates the location of the square or circle when the mouse is moved, deletes the square or circle if the mouse leaves the window, or stops updating it when the mouse is clicked (making it permanent).

I also have a class called MyPanel, which extends JPanel, and uses the paintComponent(Graphics g) method to paint the squares and circles on the background.

```
package smys01;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.text.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;




public class SMYS01 extends JFrame {

    private Color c = new Color(0, 0, 0);
    private static ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList();
    private static ArrayList<Shape> deleted = new ArrayList();

    private Point a;
    private boolean makeSquare = false, makeCircle = false, makeSquiggle = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SMYS01 window = new SMYS01();

    }
    //good main

    //0 is empty for making things, 1 is having a square selected to change, 2 is background;

    private JButton makeSquareB = new JButton("New Square" /*, add icon later*/);

    private JButton makeCircleB = new JButton("New Circle");

    private Color background = new Color(0, 150, 0);



    public SMYS01() {
        makeSquareB.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("making square");
                if(!makeCircle&&!makeSquare){
                    makeSquare = true;

                    shapes.ensureCapacity(shapes.size());
                    shapes.add(new Square((int) a.getX(), (int) a.getY(), c));
                }else if(makeSquare){

                }else if(makeCircle){
                    makeCircle=false;
                    makeSquare=true;
                    shapes.remove(shapes.size()-1);
                    shapes.ensureCapacity(shapes.size());
                    shapes.add(new Square((int) a.getX(), (int) a.getY(), c));
                }
            }
        });


        makeCircleB.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("making circle");
                if(!makeCircle&&!makeSquare){
                    makeCircle = true;
                    shapes.ensureCapacity(shapes.size());
                    shapes.add(new Circle((int) a.getX(), (int) a.getY(), c));
                }else if(makeCircle){

                }else if(makeSquare){
                    makeSquare=false;
                    shapes.remove(shapes.size()-1);
                    shapes.ensureCapacity(shapes.size());
                    shapes.add(new Circle((int) a.getX(), (int) a.getY(), c));
                }
            }
        });
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane();
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        MyPanel thing = new MyPanel();


        frame.addMouseListener(new FrameListener());
        frame.setContentPane(thing);

        frame.setSize(thing.getPreferredSize());

        frame.setTitle("Art!");

        frame.addMouseMotionListener(new FrameListener());
    }


    private class MyPanel extends JPanel {

        public MyPanel() {

            GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(this);
            layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                    layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(makeCircleB)
                    .addComponent(makeSquareB)
            );
            layout.setVerticalGroup(
                    layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(makeCircleB)
                            .addComponent(makeSquareB)
                    )
            );

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(500, 500);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(background);
            g.drawRect((int)g.getClipBounds().getX(),(int)g.getClipBounds().getY(),(int)g.getClipBounds().getWidth(),(int)g.getClipBounds().getHeight());
            g.fillRect((int)g.getClipBounds().getX(),(int)g.getClipBounds().getY(),(int)g.getClipBounds().getWidth(),(int)g.getClipBounds().getHeight());


            System.out.println(shapes.size());
            for (Shape i : shapes) {

                int[] a = i.getDim();
                g.setColor(new Color(a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7]));

                if(i instanceof Square){
                    g.drawRect(a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);
                    g.fillRect(a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);
                }else if(i instanceof Circle){
                    g.drawOval(a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);
                    g.fillOval(a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);
                }

            }

        }
    }


    class FrameListener implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {


        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("pressed");
            a = new Point(e.getPoint());
            if (makeSquare) {
                makeSquare = false;
                System.out.println("square made!");
            }
            if (makeCircle) {
                makeCircle = false;
                System.out.println("cirlce made!");
            }

            //use this for sliders, nothing else. 

        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("released");
            a = new Point(e.getPoint());
            //use for sliders, nothing else.

        }

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("clicked");
            a = new Point(e.getPoint());
            //don't need this
            //makeSquare = false;
            //makeCircle = false;

            //makeSquiggle too.
        }

        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

            //showing up as false atm
            a = new Point(e.getPoint());
            System.out.println(a);
            if (makeSquare||makeCircle) {
                Shape b = shapes.get(shapes.size()-1);
                b.updateLocation((int) a.getX(), (int) a.getY());

            }


        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            //only check if over a JSlider
        }

        //complete methods:
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("entered");
            //nothing, Mouse re-entering doesn't effect the program. 
        }

        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("exited");
            makeSquare = false;
            makeCircle = false;
            makeSquiggle = false;
            //if mouse leaves the window while trying to make one of these, stop it. 

        }
    }



}
```

code for the Shape interface:

```
package smys01;

public interface Shape {
    public void updateLocation(int newXPos, int newYPos);
    public void updateDimensions(int newXDim, int newYDim);
    public void delete();
    public void purge();
    public void restore();
    public int[] getDim();
}
```

Code for Square:
Note! this code was written a bit back, and has some parts that are not relevant at all or even complete (but are completely unused). This is for the constructor, updateDimensions() method, and the updateLocation() method

```
package smys01;
import java.awt.Color;
public class Square implements Shape{
    //tbr=to be returned.
    boolean deleted=false;
    boolean purged=false;
    private int xPos, yPos, xDim, yDim;
    private int saveXPos, saveYPos, saveXDim, saveYDim, saveR, saveG, saveB, saveA;
    private Color fill;
    public Square(int initX, int initY, Color a){
        xPos=initX;
        yPos=initY;
        xDim=50;
        yDim=50;
        fill=a;
    }
    public void updateDimensions(int newXDim, int newYDim){
        if(purged||deleted)
            return;
        if(newXDim<=2){
            xDim=2;
        }else{
            xDim=newXDim;
        }
        if(newYDim<=2){
            yDim=2;
        }else{
            yDim=newYDim;
        }

    }
    public void updateLocation(int newXPos, int newYPos){
        if(purged){
            return;
        }
        if(newXPos<=5){
            xPos=5;


        }else{
            xPos=newXPos;

        }
        if(newYPos<=25){
            yPos=25;
        }else{
            yPos=newYPos;
        }


                }
        public void delete(){
        if(!deleted){
            saveXPos=xPos;
            saveYPos=yPos;
            saveXDim=xDim;
            saveYDim=yDim;
            saveR=fill.getRed();
            saveB=fill.getBlue();
            saveG=fill.getGreen();
            saveA=fill.getAlpha();
            deleted=true;
            xPos=-5;
            yPos=-5;
            xDim=1;
            yDim=1;
                        }
    }
    public void purge(){
        saveXPos=-10;
        saveYPos=-10;
        saveXDim=3;
        saveYDim=3;
        //use in an if statement, and if true (will be, set the square value to null, so this reference will go away, preventing data overflow
    }
    public void restore(){
        xPos=saveXPos;
        yPos=saveYPos;
        xDim=saveXDim;
        yDim=saveYDim;
        deleted=false;
    }
    public int[] getDim(){
        int[] tbr={xPos,yPos, xDim, yDim,fill.getRed(), fill.getBlue(), fill.getGreen(), fill.getAlpha()};
        return tbr;
    }
    public String toString(){
        String tbr="Square: ("+xPos+", "+yPos+"); ("+xDim+", "+yDim+"); ("+fill.toString();
        return tbr;
    }

}
```

The code for the Circle class is the exact same, but the object type allows the paintComponent method to distinguish them.

I am trying to get this to call paintComponent when mouseMoved is called, however I cannot seem to get it to do this. I have tried using repaint(), and I have looked for a few hours trying to figure this out.

So far, I have seen that, basically, Swing will call paintComponent when it needs to (when window size is changed, or window is minimized and re-opened).

However, I am unsure how to call it upon pressing the button or moving the mouse, and repaint() won't work for this.

I apologize if some of the code is sloppy, I have rewritten it a few times, and some parts are unnecessary but still there.

Is there a way to actively call the paintComponent method from within the anonymous action classes or the FrameListener class?

Comment: Have you tried calling `repaint`? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes, I have tried calling repaint in both mousePressed() and mouseMoved() and it does nothing. I will include the complete code above instead for a runnable example.

Comment: Then you're going to want to create a valid [mcve], a **small**, minimal in fact, program that we can compile and run unchanged, that has no outside dependencies (such as database or images) and that directly demonstrates your problem for us.

Comment: And no, don't post the "complete code" as that will contain much code not relevant to your problem. We specifically want to see your [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Since your listener is attached to the frame and not the panel, which would seem to make sense for everything else you're doing, it's possible it's been ignored, you also seem to have two frames, which is confusing

Comment: I really want to fix this code, but I also really want to go play with my daughter. One problem you are going to have is the fact the `MouseEvent` is relative to the component that generated it.  Since you added the listener to the frame, the events will be relative to the frame, making all the coordinates offset (in the negative direction) from your panel.  The whole solution would be easier to resolve if the `MouseListener` was attached to the panel and when needed, you repainted the panel and not it's parent

Comment: @MadProgrammer You were right. It was a combination of three different things (two of which you mentioned). It needed to be added to the JPanel not the JFrame, and then repaint worked after that. However, mouseListener and MouseMotionListener needed to be added independently, so I split it into two different classes and added them one at a time. It works perfectly now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some input from @MadProgrammer, I figured out what was not working. The mouseListener was attached to the JFrame rather than the JPanel, so the events were being triggered, but paintComponent (by repaint()) was not. I added it to the panel and added repaint() to the end of the mouseMoved() method, and it is working perfectly.